# How to focus the tab in which my react application is loaded

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a requirement in which if I receive a particular socket then if that tab is minimmised it should maximise and focus should be on that tab.
I have tried window.focus() but it is not working as expected. Below is my code:

```
 window.open(data.url[0][i].field_value, "_blank")?.focus();
              window.focus();
              break;
```

---

```
const connectorWindow=window.open(data.url[0][i].field_value, "_blank"); 
connectorWindow.focus(); 
break;
```

This is maximising if the tab is minimised but not focussing the tab if it is in background. I want that tab should be focussed even if some other app is on top of it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus browser tab in which you react application has open then sorry to say but JavaScript provide limited API's for browsers. Tab management api which is `chrome.tabs.query` is not available. it will be available only when you will create browser extension and you will provide the permission to access tab API's.